# A stubborn definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Can someone help me with the integral

> $ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^2-1}{\log{x}} dx $

Tried substitution $ u = \log{x} $ but nothing came out.
Thanks to helpers.

Comment: It is $$\log(3)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner thanks, but I need the method to obtain it.